# React Native, Error while Launching Dev Tools. in ubuntu 16

Tags: react-native, react-redux, ubuntu-16.04, expo

I have installed a new react native project using create-react-native-app. When I do yarn start or npm start and scan with expo, it gives me the following error in ubuntu (when remote js debugging is on).

> Launching Dev Tools...
>       Google Chrome exited with error: Error: Exited with code 1
>           at ChildProcess. (/home/shivam/AwesomeProject/node_modules/opn/index.js:86:8)
>           at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:254:19)
>          at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
>           at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
>           at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:363:11)
>           at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)
>           at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:568:12)
>       Finished building JavaScript bundle in 95196ms
>       Stopping packager...
>       Packager stopped.
>       Done in 701.25s.

But its not the case with windows(it opens the debugger in browser).I guess in ubuntu It tries to launch debugger in browser, but somehow fails to do so. I followed some links but none of them helped.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9901

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/990

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/297

Answer (score 2):

Run `yarn` or `npm` without `sudo`, because when you enable devtools it's tries opening chrome by command (chrome won't open with sudo)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it open google chrome and hit this **url** `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui`
open console tab to debug

**`Disable Chrome cache`**

1. Right-click chrome
2. Go to 'inspect element'
3. Look for the 'network' tab somewhere at the top. Click it.
4. Check the 'disable cache' checkbox.

**Reference :**  [react-native-debugging](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

[image]

Comment: When I try to open it using url: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui . it gives me following error in console GET http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: **Step 1**  `Right click anywhere` or press `ctrl+shfit+I` on Chrome . **Step 2** Go to Console tab . you can easily debug your app and get `console output`

Comment: your server must be start `react-native start`

Comment: It triers to launch the google chrome when I scan with expo. But it says Google Chrome exited with error: Error: Exited with code 1. On navigating to  localhost:8081/debugger-ui it gives an error i.e Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I have started the serve using yarn start

Comment: `Disable Chrome cache` your Chrome Cache and then try . @Shivam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162842/discussion-between-syed-zain-ali-and-shivam).